# Ввод данных в ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Встретил в учебнике запись:

```
    //ввод строк с клавиатуры
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  String s = reader.readLine();
  list.add(s);
}
```

Зачем нужна данная запись, если ее можно записать так:

```
list.add (reader.readLine ());
```

Comment: по этому они и учебники )

Comment: Обычно вместо `s` создают какую-нибудь осмысленную переменную и тогда код легче читается.

Comment: Обычно это делается, чтобы в дальнейшем эту переменную можно было использовать до добавления в список.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой код, в котором каждое действие выполняется в отдельной строке намного удобнее отлаживать. Вы можете выполнять программу с помощью дебагера в пошаговом режиме, можете установить точку останова  на одну из строчек. Это позволит вам легко найти, в каком именно действии есть ошибка. Если же в одной строке будет нагромождение действий, номер строки с ошибкой вам мало что даст.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть цикл, то каждую итерацию будет добавлять элемент, то есть 10 раз нужно будет вводить.
Без цикла - один раз

Comment: Автор вопроса имеет ввиду для чего создают `Strign s`, если можно и без ее использования.